# Sql cast and try_cast issue for integer / currency with unknown behavior in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries as below

```
select TRY_CAST('12424.52‬' as money)

select TRY_CAST('12424.52' as money)
```

the first one returns null and second one returns correct value. How to resolve it? I believe some ascii character in the first string is causing issue. how to detect this?

Comment: Er, your queries look identical.

Comment: You have a control character between the 2 and '  in the first example

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thanks. but i did not understand that completely. can u help me to identify that?

Comment: @ManuMohanThekkedath No I am using SO on mobile currently so all I can comment on is what I can see, I'm not "trying" to be anything it's not unusual for copy and paste errors in questions. Ps I did say "look", because they do.

Comment: They *look* identical, but aren't. There's a stray `U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING` in there. Removing it is easy, if a little involved (`select convert(money, replace(N'12424.52‬' collate latin1_general_bin2, nchar(8236), ''))`), but removing "wrong" characters in general is not.

Comment: To see the offending character, you can do something like `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), N'12424.52‬')`. The results show the `0x202c` code point at the end (in little-endian, so the bytes are reversed).

Comment: thanks. @JeroenMostert  I changed my query like below and it worked

select TRY_CAST(replace(convert(varchar(4000), '12424.52‬'), '?', '')as money)

Comment: Do note that that works only for this particular control character, and only because the default collation doesn't have it. For example, `SELECT '12424.52' + CHAR(27)` may also display "correctly" (depending on your font and your editor) and won't reduce to `?` for easy replacement.

Comment: Check is exists special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this can help someone, i'm posting the workaround as a the answer

I was able to fix the issue with invisible pop directional formatting by converting the string to varchar and removing the unknown unicode chars (displayed as ? ) as below

select TRY_CAST(replace(convert(varchar(4000), '12424.52‬'), '?', '') as money)

As jeroen mentioned, this will work only if the unicode which is present in the string is unknown for your collation